# running title with reledmac

Tags: header-footer, reledmac, scrpage2

I need to set running title using reledmac. The output should be like: "דיעהאכצייטצ" (title at the left side on every page)  and "first  Act" (at the right side; counting from "first" to "fourth".
I don't have any `\chapter`s or `\section`s so I can't use `\automark[chapter]{chapter}`.

A solution could be what I found in the reledmac documentation:

> The standard sectioning commands (\chapter, \section etc.) can be used
>   inside numbered text. In this case, you must call them as an
>   optional argument of \pstart (5.2.3 p. 18):
>
> ```
>  \pstart[\section{section}]
>  Pstart content.
>  \pend
> ```

But this solution doesn't run with my code (why?) and

Example code (runs with xelatex) includes `scrheadings`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{scrbook}

\KOMAoptions
  {
    fontsize=10pt,
    paper=24cm:17cm,
    pagesize=pdftex,
    DIV=calc,
  }
  \usepackage{leading}
  \leading{12pt}

  \usepackage[
    paperwidth=17cm,
    paperheight=24cm,
    top=3.45cm,
    bottom=8.04cm,
    inner=4.15cm,
    outer=4.85cm,
  ]{geometry}

\usepackage{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot

\ihead{\headmark}


\ohead{\pagemark}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\normalfont\normalcolor\small}\setkomafont{pagenumber}{\normalfont}

\addtokomafont{pagehead}{\normalfont}

\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalcolor\bfseries}

\clubpenalty=10000
\widowpenalty=10000

\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage[series={A,B,C}]{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{multicol,multirow, bigdelim}%%times RAUS
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia, xunicode}
\usepackage{libertine}

\setmainlanguage{german}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}


\newcommand\einzugjid{\hangindent=5mm\hangafter=1}

\newcommand\speaker[1]{\noindent{#1} \einzugjid
}

\newcommand\einzug{\hangindent=5mm\hangafter=1}

\newcommand\speakerd[1]{\noindent
{\textsc{#1}} \einzug
}


\begin{document}

\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside}
 \setRTL
 \beginnumbering
%%%4.1
\pstart {\Large{{\RL{\textbf{פיערטער אויפצוג:}}}}}{{\begin{small}|\liningnums{96}|\end{small}}} \pend
\pstart {\RL{\textit{(האָכצייטסשטובע אַנדערער טאַג)}}} \pend

\pstart {\Large{{\RL{\textbf{ערשטער אויפטריטט.}}}}} \pend
\pstart {\RL{יוקב. חתן. מאֶננער אונד ווייבער.}} \pend




\pstart  {\RL{\speaker{יוקב.}
 \textit{(צום חתן האֶניש)}
  נוא דוא באָרגסט מער דאָך דיע נדיניה ביס נויך דעם
\linebreak {שמאַלשטאֶדטער}
  מאַרק?
  { }}}
  \pend
 %\footnotetextB[\ref{4a1}]{{\RL{חתן}}: \LR{‘Bräutigam’, \parencite[§\,493, §\,590]{Tendlau1860} \textit{Chosen}, \parencite[87]{Weinberg1994} \textit{cho\={s}on}, \textit{cho\={s}en}; {\textless} hebr. \RL{חתן}.}}
%\footnotetextB[\ref{4a1}]{{\RL{נדיניה}}: \LR{‘Mitgift’, \parencite[§\,197]{Tendlau1860} und  \parencite[86]{Weinberg1973} \textit{nedinje}, \parencite[S.\,83 Karte 28]{GuggenheimGruenberg1973} Informantin aus Hessen (Kirchhain) \textit{nedinje}. Die in Hessen zu erwartende Vokalisierung \textit{nedinje} entspricht der westjiddischen Palatalisierung mit nachfolgender Entrundung von Schureq im westlichen Teil des Westjiddischen; im östlichen Teil findet man hingegen \textit{nedunja} \parencite[82]{GuggenheimGruenberg1973}. Nach \parencite[95]{Birnbaum1979} ein für das Westjiddische typisches Lemma. Im mod. Jiddisch ist ʻdowryʼ als \RL{נדן} [NADN] belegt \parencite[95]{Weinreich2008}. Möglicherweise von hebr. \RL{נתן} aus ass. \textit{nadânu} ‘gebenʼ, ‘Gabeʼ%, was später talm. zu \RL{נְדוּנְיׇא} \parencite[\textcolor{red}{488, 529f, 487}]{Gesenius1962}.}}
%\footnotetextB[\ref{4a1}]{{\RL{שמאַלשטאֶדטע}}: \LR{‘Schamlstadt' wohl ein Phantasiename.}}

 \pstart {\RL{\speaker{חתן[.]}
 {כלומר},
  איהר בעגעהרט ניט געבאָרגט. יוקב גראָבסדאָרף בעגעהרט צו
  באָרגע. נוא, מאַכט פאָרט און צֵיעהלט! עס איס באַלד מיטטאַג.}}
   \pend
% \footnotetextB[\ref{4b1}]{{\RL{כלומר}}: \LR{‘das heißt, nämlich', {\textless} hebr. \RL{כלומר} \textit{k'lomar} ‘as thought one said', ‘that is to say', ‘this means' \parencite[640]{Jastrow1975}.}}
% \footnotetextB[\ref{4b1}]{{\RL{יוקב גראָבסדאָרף}}: \LR{Nachname Jakobs entspricht dem Ort der Handlung.}}

\pstart  {\RL{\speaker{ויקב.} נויכמיטטאַג נעמסט דוא‘ס גאַר ניט.}} \pend

 \pstart  {\RL{\speaker{חתן.}
   וויעס אויסגעהאַלטע איס,
   {קורם}
    העחופה צו ליווערע,
    ד{ו\makebox[2pt][l]{\libertineGlyph{uni05C1}}}\makebox[-2pt][r]{}א
     מוס אַהך
        געשֵיעה}}
         \pend
 % \footnotetextB[\ref{4c1}]{{\RL{קורם}}: \LR{ wohl ‘Gelegenheit', ‘Zeitpunkt' {\textless} hebr. \RL{קֵירָס} ‘opportunity, season' \parencite[1369]{Jastrow1975}.}}
 %\footnotetextB[\ref{4c1}]{{ \RL{העחופה}}: \LR{‘Baldachin, Hochzeitszelt, Trauhimmel’, \parencite[§\,463]{Tendlau1860} \textit{Chuppe}, \parencite[88]{Weinberg1973} \textit{chuppo}, \textit{chuppe}, {\textless} hebr. \RL{חפה} ‘Thronhimmel, Baldachin’ \parencite[249]{Gesenius1962} mit Artikel \RL{הע-} {\textless} hebr. \RL{הַ-}.}}

\pstart {\RL{\speaker{יוקב.}
 עס ברויך דיר ניט אַנגשט צו זייא.
 דוא זאָללסט דייא געלד קריעה. אָבער
  {חובות}
   מוסטע
{{\begin{small}|\lnums{97}|\end{small}}}
אַהנעממע. {בטוח}ה חובות.}}
 \pend
% \footnotetextB[\ref{4d1}]{{\RL{חובות}}: \LR{hier ‘Schulden', auch ‘Pflichten', \parencite[84]{Weinberg1994} \textit{Chauwau\={s}}, {\textless} hebr. \RL{חוב} ‘Schuld' \parencite[216]{Gesenius1962}.}}
% \footnotetextB[\ref{4e1}]{{\RL{חובות}}: \LR{ hier ‘Schulden', auch ‘Pflichten', \parencite[84]{Weinberg1994} \textit{Chauwau\={s}}, {\textless} hebr. \RL{חוב} ‘Schuld' \parencite[216]{Gesenius1962} Lorem Ipsum: hebr. nicht bei Weinberg!.}}
 %\footnotetextB[\ref{4e1}]{{\RL{בטוחה}}: \LR{hier ‘gewisse', auch ‘zuverlässig, vermögend, wohlhabend, geachtet, sicher’, \parencite[§\,195]{Tendlau1860} \textit{Betuechter}, \parencite[4]{Frank1962} \textit{betuucht}, \parencite[52]{Weinberg1973} \textit{betūcht}, \textit{betūcht}, \textit{betūach} , {\textless} hebr. \RL{בטוח}.}}
%}}



\pstart {\RL{\speaker{איין מאן.}
 נוא, ווען דיע {חובות} גוט זען קאַן ער זיע אַהך אַנעממע.
 זיע מיססע
  ליקריט זייא דיע
  {חובות}. פערשטֵירער מיך?
  {ליקריט}.}} \pend
%\footnotetextB[\ref{4f1}]{{\RL{חובות}}: \LR{hier ‘Schulden', auch ‘Pflichten', \parencite[84]{Weinberg1994} \textit{Chauwau\={s}}, {\textless} hebr. \RL{חוב} ‘Schuld' \parencite[216]{Gesenius1962} Lorem Ipsum: hebr. nicht bei Weinberg!.}}
%\footnotetextB[\ref{4f1}]{{\RL{ליקריט}}: \LR{Wohl ‘liquid'.}}
%\footnotetextB[\ref{4g1}]{{\RL{חובות}}: \LR{hier ‘Schulden', auch ‘Pflichten', \parencite[84]{Weinberg1994} \textit{Chauwau\={s}}, {\textless} hebr. \RL{חוב} ‘Schuld' \parencite[216]{Gesenius1962} Lorem Ipsum: hebr. nicht bei Weinberg!.}}
%\footnotetextB[\ref{4g1}]{{\RL{ליקריט}}: \LR{Lorem ipsum}}

\pstart  {\RL{\speaker{ויקב.}
  שמה ישראל! וואַר איך עהן דען
  {מכמה}
   זייא!
  וואַר איך דען מיים אַהרעם
   {שויפעללע}
  {חובות} געבע?
   איך העררעם גערן לוירער
    באַאַר געלד געבע;
    מער קאַן
    י{ו\makebox[2pt][l]{\libertineGlyph{uni05C1}}}\makebox[-2pt][r]{}א
     פֿון קאַהם
     {כפרה}
      ניקס קריעה.
     איך האָן ערשט דיע פֿאָריגע
    וואוך אַהן אוף
     \~{{\RL{}}}ב
      {חדשה}
       \~{{\RL{}}}רט
    פערקרויבענד \textit{(פֿערקלאגט)} מער קריגט יוא
     ניקס צו זאָממע. דען חוב קאַנסט דוא אָבער
     אַהך אַהנעממע.
}}    \pend
%\footnotetextB[\ref{4h1}]{{\RL{שמה ישראל!}}: \LR{‘höre Israel!' {\textless} hebr. \RL{ ‏שְׁמַע יִשְׂרָאֵל}, psycho-ostensiver Ausdruck (vgl. \cite{Matisoff2000}).}}
%\footnotetextB[\ref{4h1}]{{\RL{מכמה}}: \LR{‘(Braut-)verkäufer' {\textless} \RL{מכר} \parencite[422]{Gesenius1962}.}}%\footnotetextB[\ref{4h1}]{{\RL{מכמה}}: \LR{Verb mit hebr. Partizip.}}
%\footnotetextB[\ref{4i1}]{{\RL{שויפעללע}}: \LR{Dim. Sg. -\textit{elle}.}}
%\footnotetextB[\ref{4j1}]{{\RL{חובות}}: \LR{hier ‘Schulden', auch ‘Pflichten', \parencite[84]{Weinberg1994} \textit{Chauwau\={s}}, {\textless} hebr. \RL{חוב} ‘Schuld' \parencite[216]{Gesenius1962} Lorem Ipsum: hebr. nicht bei Weinberg!.}}
%\footnotetextB[\ref{4j1}]{{\RL{קאַהם … ניקס}}: \LR{Mehrfachnegation.}}
%\footnotetextB[\ref{4k1}]{{\RL{כפרה}}: \LR{‘Sühne', \parencite[u.\,a. §\,198, §\,438, §\,445, §\,994]{Tendlau1860} \textit{Kappore}, \parencite[143]{Weinberg1994} \textit{kaporo}, -\textit{kapore}, {\textless} hebr. \RL{כפרה}.}}
%\footnotetextB[\ref{4k1}]{{\RL{חדשה}}: \LR{‘neue', \parencite[79]{Weinberg1994} \textit{chadëisch} {\textless} hebr. imp. \RL{חדש} ‘erneuere!'}}
%\footnotetextB[\ref{4l1}]{{\RL{חוב}}: \LR{hier ‘Schuld', auch ‘Pflicht', \parencite[84]{Weinberg1994} \textit{Chauwau\={s}}, {\textless} hebr. \RL{חוב} ‘Schuld' \parencite[216]{Gesenius1962} Lorem Ipsum: hebr. nicht bei Weinberg!.}}


\pstart {\RL{\speaker{חתן.}
 נוא, דען ווילל איך אייך אַהך אייער דאָכטער באָרגע. איך ברויך קאַה
 פֿראַה מיט {חובות}.
 מער קאַן בייא דער
 {שויפֿעללע}
  צייט בעונות
הובות גענונג מאַכע, ווען מער געבאָרגט
 קריגט. מיננע שמה.}}
  \pend
%\footnotetextB[\ref{4m1}]{{\RL{חובות}}: \LR{hier ‘Schulden', auch ‘Pflichten', \parencite[84]{Weinberg1994} \textit{Chauwau\={s}}, {\textless} hebr. \RL{חוב} ‘Schuld' \parencite[216]{Gesenius1962} Lorem Ipsum: hebr. nicht bei Weinberg!.}}
%\footnotetextB[\ref{4n1}]{{\RL{בעונות}}: \LR{wörtl. ‘Sünden’; nach \parencite[70]{Weinberg1973} \textit{bewaunes̄} „Interj. Ausruf des Schreckens oder Erstaunens, der Angst oder Sorge“. Psycho-ostensiver Ausdruck (\cite{Matisoff2000}). s.\,a. \textcolor{cyan}{{\RL{בעונותנו האראם}}}.}} %s. Aufzug 1  \ref{1c1}]{{\RL{בעונותנו האַראַם}}: \LR{Wohl zu \textit{báawoonooseenu horabbim} ‘um unserer Sünden willen’ (\cite[§\,639, §\,931]{Tendlau1860}, \cite[60]{Weinberg1994}).}}

%\footnotetextB[\ref{4n1}]{{\RL{הובות}}: \LR{hier ‘Schulden', auch ‘Pflichten', \parencite[84]{Weinberg1994} \textit{Chauwau\={s}}, {\textless} hebr. \RL{חוב} ‘Schuld' \parencite[216]{Gesenius1962} Lorem Ipsum: hebr. nicht bei Weinberg!.}}
%\footnotetextB[\ref{4o1}]{{\RL{מיננע שמה}}: \LR{‘meine Seeleʼ, \parencite[§\,339]{Tendlau1860} \textit{mein Neschome}, \parencite[87]{Weinberg1973} \textit{Mei’ neschome!}  oder \textit{meine ‘schome!}, hier liegt eine Umdeutung der Wortgrenze des hebr. Nomens \RL{ נשמה} ‘Seeleʼ in Verbindung des deutschen Pronomens \textit{Mei} vor, die durch die Graphie deutlich wird (vgl. \cite[43]{Weinberg1973}), Psycho-ostensiver Ausdruck (vgl. \cite[19--21]{Matisoff2000}).}}


\pstart {\RL{\speaker{איין מאַן.}
 ווען זיע {חובות} גוט זען אן ער דיר
{{\begin{small}|\liningnums{98}|\end{small}}}
שריפֿטליך געבט, דאַס ער דיר גוט דערפאָר איס,
 קאַנסטו זע אַהך אַהנעממע.}}
 \pend

\pstart  {\RL{\speaker{ויקב.}
 י{ו\makebox[2pt][l]{\libertineGlyph{uni05C1}}}\makebox[-2pt][r]{}א,
  ד{ו\makebox[2pt][l]{\libertineGlyph{uni05C1}}}\makebox[-2pt][r]{}א
   ווילל איך עהם גוט דערפֿאָר זייא.
  וואַר איך דען מייא אַהרעם
   {שופללע}
   {חובות} געבע? ער איס
    י{ו\makebox[2pt][l]{\libertineGlyph{uni05C1}}}\makebox[-2pt][r]{}א
     אַללעווייל
      אַז{ו\makebox[2pt][l]{\libertineGlyph{uni05C1}}}\makebox[-2pt][r]{}א
       גוט, אַס וויע מייא אַיע קינד.
    אונזער האַריעט
    זאָלל מער מייא
    {נעווערעס}
     {מוחל}
      זייא.}}
     \pend
%\footnotetextB[\ref{4p1}]{{\RL{חובות}}: \LR{hier ‘Schulden', auch ‘Pflichten', \parencite[84]{Weinberg1994} \textit{Chauwau\={s}}, {\textless} hebr. \RL{חוב} ‘Schuld' \parencite[216]{Gesenius1962} Lorem Ipsum: hebr. nicht bei Weinberg!.}}
%\footnotetextB[\ref{4p1}]{{\RL{האַריעט}}: \LR{{‘Herr, Gott’, \parencite[93]{Tendlau1860} \textit{Harjet}.}}}
%\footnotetextB[\ref{4q1}]{{\RL{נעווערעס}}: \LR{Ggf. ‘Narrheiten', vgl. Z. \ref{nebbich}.}}%vgl. Aufzug 1: {\RL{נעוויך}}: \LR{‘leider, Gott bewahre, Interjektion’, \parencite[§\,633]{Tendlau1860} \textit{newich} aber auch \textit{nebich}, \citeauthor{Weinberg1973} (\cite[86]{Weinberg1973}) \textit{nebbich}, Etymologie unklar (vgl. \cite[111]{Weinberg1973}). Psycho-ostensiver Ausdruck (vgl. \cite[19--21]{Matisoff2000})
%\footnotetextB[\ref{4q1}]{{\RL{מוחל}}: \LR{‘zugute halten, vergeben, entschuldigen', \parencite[§\,364, §\,459]{Tendlau1860} \textit{Mochel sein}, \parencite[79]{Weinberg1973} \textit{mauchel}, \textit{m\={o}chel}, {\textless} hebr. \RL{מוחל} periphrastisches Verb mit hebr. Partizip.}}

\pstart {\RL{\speaker{חתן.}
 נוא, דען צֵיהלט. דאַס געווערט גאַה לאַנג.
}} \pend


\pstart {\RL{\speaker{יוקב.}
 איך האָן ניקס צו איילע.
  \textit{(פיר זיך)}
 בעונות איץ גֵיהט מייא אַהעם געלדכע צו
 \gls{שָטָן}
 }} \pend

     \endnumbering
\end{Leftside}


\begin{Rightside}

\beginnumbering
\pstart  {\Large \textbf{Vierter Aufzug}} \pend
\pstart  \textit{(Hochzeitsstube. Anderer Tag.)}     \pend

\pstart {\Large \textbf{Erster Auftritt}} \pend
\pstart  \textit{Jakob. Bräutigam. Mädchen und Weiber.} \pend

\pstart \speakerd{Jakob} \textit{(zum Bräutigam höhnisch)}. Nun, du borgst mir doch die Mitgift bis nach dem Schmalstädter Markt? \pend

\pstart \speakerd{Bräutigam.} Das heißt Ihr begehrt, nicht geborgt. Jakob Grobsdorf begehrt zu borgen. Nun, macht zu und zahlt! Es ist bald Mittag. \pend

\pstart \speakerd{Jakob.} Nachmittag nimmst du es gar nicht? \pend

\pstart \speakerd{Bräutigam.} Wie es ausgemacht ist. Der Zeitpunkt zu liefern ist unter dem Baldachin, da muss es auch geschehen. \pend

\pstart \speakerd{Jakob.} Es braucht dir nicht Angst zu sein. Du sollst dein Geld kriegen. Aber Schulden musst du annehmen. Bestimmte Schulden.  \pend

\pstart \speakerd{Ein Mann.} Nun, wenn die Schulden gut sind, kann er sie auch annehmen. Sie müssten liquide sein, die Schulden. Versteht ihr mich? Liquid. \pend

\pstart \speakerd{Jakob.} \textit{Sche'ma Israel}! Werde ich ihm denn ein Brautverkäufer sein! Werde ich denn meinem Armen schlechte Schulden geben? Ich hätte ihm gerne lauter Bargeld gegeben; man kann ja von keinem Vergebung kriegen. Ich habe erst die vorige Woche auf zwei neue 209 verklagt. Man kriegt ja nichts zusammen. Die Schuld kannst du aber auch annehmen. \pend

\pstart \speakerd{Bräutigam.} Nun, dann will ich von euch auch eure Tochter borgen. Ich brauche keine Frau mit Schulden. Man kann bei der schlechten Zeit sündige Schulden genug machen, wenn man geborgt kriegt. Meine Seele. \pend

\pstart \speakerd{Ein Mann.} Werden die Schulden gut sein und er dir schriftlich gibt, dass dir gut davor ist, kannst du sie auch annehmen. \pend

\pstart \speakerd{Jakob.} Ja, da will ich ihm gut davor sein. Werde ich denn meinem Armen schlechte Schulden geben? Er ist ja immer so gut, wie mein eigenes Kind. Unser Herrgott soll mir meine Narrheiten vergeben. \pend

\pstart \speakerd{Bräutigam.} Nun, dann zahlt, das gewehrt gar lang. \pend

\pstart \speakerd{Jakob.} Ich habe nichts zu eilen. \textit{(Für sich.)} Sünde! Jetzt geht mein armes Geldchen zu Satan! \pend


\endnumbering

\end{Rightside}

\end{pages}
\Pages


\end{document}
```

Comment: After 4 years of membership you should know, that mega code is not enough. And nobody should need to ask you for a MWE …

Comment: The MWE runs for me!

Comment: **Minimal** working example?

Comment: As minimal as possible

Comment: Do you really need all the lines to reproduce the problem? Can you at least mark the line, where you use `\pstart` with *optional* argument? I cannot find any. And where is `\speaker` defined? And do you use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX?

Comment: There are still undefined control sequences and I still cannot find any `\pstart[…]` but several `\pstart … \pend`, where I do not understand why you use an extra group. BTW: `\Large` does not have an argument.

Comment: without MWE, I won't work on this issue.

Comment: but it is an working example!

Comment: it is a working example, but not a Minimal (minimal is an import word),

Comment: it's only two pages (left and right) –

Comment: 1. It is not working (I get `! Undefined control sequence.
l.118 {{\begin{small}|\lnums
                            {97}|\end{small}}}
`)

Comment: 2. It is not minimal (there is note needed line)

Answer (score 0):

It works with using `\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}` and `\pstart[{\addsec{Vierter Aufzug}}]\pend`

[Code can be found here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/407276/hidden-chapter-in-header-using-scrpage2/407286?noredirect=1#407286)

thank to @Schweinebacke