# Hidden \chapter* in header using scrpage2

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, scrpage2

How can I include a "hidden" `\section*{}` or `\chapter*{}` in the header (centered) using `scrpage2`?

```
  \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrbook}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

    \usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}
    \pagestyle{scrheadings}
    \chead{\headmark}
    \ohead{\pagemark}
    \automark[chapter*]{section*}  %%leftpageheader: chapter* / rightpagehaeder: section*
    \begin{document}
    \chapter*{Bla}

    \pagebreak

    \section*{Blub}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: Do you just want unnumbered chapers and sections?

Comment: Yes. unnumbered

Comment: Do you use `\chapter*` here to have an unnumbered chapter or to prevent the chapter from being in toc (or both)?

Comment: @TeXnician I just don't want any numbers. (but I want other parts of the book with numbered chapters as well)

Comment: Please note: `scrpage2` is obsolete. You should use [`scrlayer-scrpage`](http://ctan.org/pkg/scrlayer-scrpage) instead of `scrpage2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scrbook` like `book` does not provide automatic running head for `\chapter*` and `\section*`. If everything should be unnumbered, set `\secnumdepth` to -2 and use `\chapter` and `\section` instead of `\chapter*` and `\section*`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\chead{\headmark}
\ohead{\pagemark}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2}%
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Bla}

\section{Blub}

\Blindtext[10]

\end{document}
```

If you have numbered and not numbered chapters and section, you can use:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\chead{\headmark}
\ohead{\pagemark}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\chapter*{Bla}
\markboth{\MakeUppercase{Bla}}{}

\section{Blub}
\markright{\MakeUppercase{Blub}}

\Blindtext[10]

\end{document}
```

But using `scrbook` it is more easy to use `\addchap` and `\addsec`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\chead{\headmark}
\ohead{\pagemark}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\addchap{Bla}

\addsec{Blub}

\Blindtext[10]

\end{document}
```

If you want to avoid the ToC entries:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,headings=optiontotoc]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\chead{\headmark}
\ohead{\pagemark}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addchap[]{Bla}

\addsec[]{Blub}

\Blindtext[10]

\end{document}
```

And please note, that `scrpage2` is obsolete. You should use `scrlayer-scrpage`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,headings=optiontotoc]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\chead{\headmark}
\ohead{\pagemark}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addchap[]{Bla}

\addsec[]{Blub}

\Blindtext[10]

\end{document}
```

See the [KOMA-Script manual](https://komascript.de/scrguien) or the [German KOMA-Script manual](https://komascript.de/scrguide) or the [German KOMA-Script book](https://komascript.de/komascriptbuch) for more information about `scrlayer-scrpage`, `\addchap`, `\addsec` and option `headings`.

Comment: Thank you @Schweinebacke – but what if I want numbered and unnumbered `\chapter`in the same document (like an unnumbered appendix)?

Comment: @לאהפּאַסטעך See the additional examples.

Comment: Thank you both! the `addchap` / `addsec` command is new to me, but much better than the "old" `\chapter*`
And thanks for the information that `scrpage2`is obsolete!

Answer (score 3):

As your intention is to get unnumbered sections or chapters you can use KOMA's commands `\addchap` and `\addsec` which will produce unnumbered headings, but set the head marks and add the title to toc.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\chead{\headmark}
\ohead{\pagemark}
\automark[chapter]{section}  %%leftpageheader: chapter* / rightpagehaeder: section*
\begin{document}
\addchap{Bla}

\pagebreak

\addsec{Blub}

\pagebreak
test
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! I think using `\addchap`is the best idea here!